# Jquery Mobile Form negative numbers need removing

Tags: jquery, forms, mobile

Hi in Jquery Mobile form entry

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="price">Price:</label>
    <input id="priceField" name="price" type="number" data-role="none" value="{{price}}" >
</div>
```

Issue the number selectors show negative numbers
Objective  I want the selectors to be in positive whole numbers only

Is this possible is there another type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use min attribute which have to be set at 0 like

```
<input id="priceField" name="price" type="number" min="0" data- role="none"
         value="{{price}}" >
```